# WCF data contract question

Tags: wcf

I have this data contract:

```
[DataContract(Namespace = Constants.ServiceNamespace)]
public enum UserEntityType
{
    User = 0,
    Group = 1,
    IPAddress = 2 
}

[DataContract(Namespace = Constants.ServiceNamespace)]
//[KnownType(typeof(UserEntity))]
public class UserEntity
{
    [DataMember]
    public UserEntityType EntityType;
    [DataMember]
    public string Value;
}

[DataContract(Namespace = Constants.ServiceNamespace)]
public class TemporaryPolicyData
{
    [DataMember]
    public DateTime EndTime;
    [DataMember]
    public string URL;
}

[DataContract(Namespace = Constants.ServiceNamespace)]
//[KnownType(typeof(TemporaryPolicyData))]
//[KnownType(typeof(UserEntity))]
public class TemporaryWhitelistData
{
    [DataMember]
    public UserEntity User;
    [DataMember]
    public TemporaryPolicyData Data;
}

[DataContract(Namespace = Constants.ServiceNamespace)]
//[KnownType(typeof(TemporaryWhitelistData))]
//[KnownType(typeof(UserEntity))]
public class WhitelistPolicyData
{
    [DataMember]
    public IEnumerable<TemporaryWhitelistData> TemporaryData;
    [DataMember]
    public IEnumerable<string> Websites;
    [DataMember]
    public IEnumerable<UserEntity> Users;
}
```

I get this error:

> An unhandled exception of type
>   'System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException' occurred in
>   mscorlib.dll
>
> Additional information: There was an error reading from the pipe: The
>   pipe has been ended. (109, 0x6d)

This seems to be related to the data contract defined above, because if I simplify it, it returns data.

The operation method that gives this error is:

```
[OperationContract]
WhitelistPolicyData GetWhitelistPolicy();
```

Comment: Any InnerExceptions? What do you mean by saying *simplyfied*?

Comment: The inner exception says "Additional information: There was an error reading from the pipe: The pipe has been ended. (109, 0x6d)". Simplified means that I excluded from WhitelistPolicyData
fields TemporaryData and Users

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there has to be a more meaningful inner exception of type `SerializationException`.

The only thing i see is the missing `[EnumMember]` attributes on your enumeration. Try this:

```
[DataContract]
public enum UserEntityType
{
    [EnumMember]
    User = 0,
    [EnumMember]
    Group = 1,
    [EnumMember]
    IPAddress = 2 
}
```

See [the docu on msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa347875.aspx) for an explantion. When putting `[DataContract]` on an enumeration you have to specify the `[EnumMember]` attribute as well.

Comment: There is just another thing that I noticed. In case IEnumerable<TemporaryWhitelistData> is something that is lazy evaluated and you don't force evaluation by transforming it to List() that I get the same errors (.NET serializer seems not to evaluate the lazy IEnumerable<> at serialization time)

Comment: The DataContract serializer evaluates all public properties marked with the `DataMember` attribute. So i can't acknowledge that. Maybe the evaluation of your IEnumerable is not possible any more at the time the serializer accesses it.